# How do I prove a graph is non planar?

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, planar-graphs

[image: Question]

Using $E\le 3N - 6$

$$13\le 30$$

and using $E \le 2N - 4$

$$13\le 20$$

but I need to show that the graph is non planar

How can I?

Is it a subgraph of $K_{3,3}$?

Comment: When $V-E+F\ne2$, the graph cannot be planar.

Comment: It "is" not a subdivision. It *contains* a subdivision. Sure you need to prove that you have actually spotted that subgraph (which is a subdivision of $K3,3$) rather than just *claiming* that there is one.

Answer (score 2):

Spot a subdivision of the $K3,3$ graph in your graph:

[image: Subdivision]

As $K3,3$ is not planar, your graph cannot be planar either.